# Passing Oracle UDT to stored procedure throws error on ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I've been hitting a wall over this for the last two days. In essence I have created UDT using Oracle tools for Visual Studio (ODAC 12c Release 3 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.1)), added needed attributes.

The object I'm passing is an UDT object, having a collection of UDT which wraps around some properties.

As good as it works when pulling data from database it throws a fit when trying to pass UDT object as a parameter to stored procedure.
I checked all that came to mind: 
- types;
- command configuration: type set to OracleType.Object (tried with array - no change);

And here is the error with the call stack:

> "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly."
>
> at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_Location()
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetAllReferencedAssemblies()
>
> at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.RegAndConfigRdr.setudtmapping(Hashtable&
>   s_mapUdtNameToMappingObj)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetCustomTypeMappings()
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetUdtName(String
>   customTypeName, String dataSource)
>
> at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetUDTFromCustomObject(OracleConnection
>   conn, IOracleCustomType customObj, Int32 i)
>
> at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_OracleObject(OracleConnection
>   conn)
>
> at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Object(OracleConnection
>   conn)
>
> at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection
>   conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> at OracleDatabaseHelper.OracleCommandEx.ExecuteNonQuery()