# Oracle DataAccess related: "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly."

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, dll, gac

I understand that such an error has been discussed multiple times on SO. Some turned that was a bug in DLL file, some resolved by changing DLL version, other didn't seem to have a clue. Anyway I just post to try my luck:

My application crashed when selecting a row in a grid on a C# GUI. The stackTrace looks like:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.
at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetAllReferencedAssemblies()
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.RegAndConfigRdr.setudtmapping(Hashtable& s_mapUdtNameToMappingObj)
at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_Location()
at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.SetCustomTypeMappings()
at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetUdtName(String customTypeName, String dataSource)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetUDTFromCustomObject(OracleConnection conn, IOracleCustomType customObj, Int32 i)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_OracleObject(OracleConnection conn)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Object(OracleConnection conn)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

my coworkers didn't experience this problem so I figure it has something to do with my local machine.

I looked up the Oracle.DataAccess.dll in GAC, it looks like (I used .Net 4.0, under c:/windows/Microsoft.NET/assembly):

```
find . -name "Oracle.*DataAccess*.dll"
./GAC_32/Oracle.DataAccess/v4.0_4.121.2.0__89b483f429c47342/Oracle.DataAccess.dll
./GAC_MSIL/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/v4.0_4.121.2.0__89b483f429c47342/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

My coworkers used: V2.121.3.0 and no managed dll. The reason why my DLL being different from theirs is that I use VS2015 vs. they VS2013, and it took me a while to figure out the right (at least by that time) Oracle DLLs that get the app built and run under VS2015.

The closest post is here: [Passing Oracle UDT to stored procedure throws error on ExecuteNonQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110671/passing-oracle-udt-to-stored-procedure-throws-error-on-executenonquery) but it didn't have a solution.

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: You can use both V2.121.3.0 and V4.121.2.0 on any version of Visual Studio. However, installed version must match .NET target compiler settings, i.e. you must set target version to 3.0 or higher for version 4.xxx. In order to use version 2.xxx the compiler target version must be 2.0 (or lower which is not available anymore)

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, sorry I can only run&test the application binary - I don't have the source. :-(

Comment: Then talk to the person who provided the binary

Comment: Are you by chance selecting from a table with an SDO_Geometry? I'm having this issue when the ManagedDataAccess dll is loaded into the process at the same time as DataAccess and trying to ExecuteReader from the unmanaged client on a table that has an SDO_Geometry type.

Comment: @matrixugly did either of you have any luck with this issue ? We are getting the same NotSupportedException when trying to migrate from Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.3.0 to 2.121.2.0 ... Thing is, when you look at the Oracle.DataAccess dll code they do check on (!assembly.IsDynamic ) before calling assembly.Location

Comment: @AardVark71 I think we opted to use the unmanaged client when sdo_geometry was needed. We didn't have a choice sadly. :(

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still have this issue. The same thing happened to me when I tried to upgrade Oracle Driver from 11.* to 12.*.

I found that at runtime, it load both 2.12* and 4.12* Oracle.DataAccess assembly from GAC.

The quick solution is simply do a runtime assembly redirect to 4.12* since our app target at .Net Framework 4.*.
My preferred solution is migrate to use Managed Oracle Driver NuGet version.

I still didn't figure out why it throw the exception even if in the dll they checked (!assembly.IsDynamic ) as @AardVark71 mentioned. But that line "assembly.Location" is introduced in 12.* Oracle Driver. Also not quite sure why it loaded two version of Oracle.DataAccess Assembly