# Incomprehensible problem between MongoDB and Oracle (dynamic assembly)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, oracle, oracle-spatial

I've got a similar problem like [Oracle DataAccess related: "The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889849/oracle-dataaccess-related-the-invoked-member-is-not-supported-in-a-dynamic-ass)

I've got the same Oracle exception ("the invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly").
However, I think the Oracle version is not the problem since the program worked fine before that, and the Oracle version is the same. It's related to the support of a custom oracle data type (SdoGeometry).

```
[OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY")]
public class SdoGeometry : OracleCustomTypeBase<SdoGeometry> { ... }
```

**Note: it worked well until now.**

The program tries to get some data from an oracle database and computes and stores result in MongoDB database. Since there have been recent developments on the MongoDB part (what's the connection? I'm getting there), i'm getting the exception in some cases.

So, the program works as follow:

```
1. If there is data in MongoDB, the program checks it
2. The program selects data in Oracle and prepares it
3. It stores data in MongoDB
```

The (**sometimes**) failing operation is in step 2: it consists in adding colums type names in the output data, like this:

```
private void ReadTypes(Dictionary<string, string> types, DbDataReader reader){
   if (types.Count == 0) {
      int fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
      for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++) {
         string fieldName = reader.GetName(i);
         try {
            string fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(i).Name;
            types[fieldName] = fieldType;
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
            // the invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly
            // only for SdoGeometry type
         }
      }
   }
}
```

OracleDataReader.GetFieldType(i) fails for SdoGeometry type (our custom data type) only when step 1 is executed (there is some MongoDB operations). I've identified the responsible operation, it's:

```
mongoEvents = mongoEvents_.Find(e => e.Identifier.Table.Equals(table)).ToList();
```

(by moving an if-true-return block from line to line - on a part of the application that I did not show  -  I identified that it was this operation that produced the error).

This operation consists in extracting from Mongo, the data already archived for the current Oracle table. It's an operation for MongoAPI (IMongoCollection.Find). So:

- If I comment this line and return an empty list (or with a manually inserted object), there is no more exception. Well...
- But what is strange is this:

```
//I've replaced the previous statement. 
//It's working, no mongo data is returned but this is independent of step 2, 
//which in any case retrieves data from Oracle database.

//(MongoDataEvent is one of our classes which defines the structure of archived data)

mongoEvents = new List<MongoEvent.MongoDataEvent>();
```

Okay, but if instead of that, I add this statment after the previous one:

```
mongoEvents = mongoEvents_.Find(e => e.Identifier.Table.Equals(table)).ToList();
mongoEvents = new List<MongoEvent.MongoDataEvent>();
```

Okay it's useless, but **when emptying the list after performing the Find method, the exception appears again (not while calling Find, but after while calling GetFieldType), while the list is empty.**

So...I don't have any idea what's going on. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: the call `reader.GetFieldType(i)` fails when the type is `SDO_GEOMETRY` **and** if sometimes before you have done some mongodb-specific operation ?

Comment: But you also say that this **sometimes** fails, even when preceded by the mongodb incantations ? Could it be that in only happens with certain types of geometry objects you fetch ? The SDO_GEOMETRY type contains several other object types, and also some arrays (Oracle `VARRAY` types). Could it be related to the size of those arrays ? One of the arrays contains the coordinates of the points that form a geometry. Could it be that the problem only manifests itself when this number is large ? It could go up to 1000000.

Comment: The app is always working the same way: 1) it check if MongoDb data still refers to existing data in Oracle, 2) fill mongodb with latest oracle data. SdoGeometry is always correct when mongodb is initially empty (first launch of the app). All SdoGeometry are ok and stored in mongoDb. But, when the app is launched a second time, it performs 1) and 2) -> when it's 2), the program systematically fails when reading SdoGeometry from oracle data (the same function is used).. Error is like "the called member is not supported in a dynamic assembly" (only for SdoGeometry, other fields are ok).

Comment: OK Thanks. So it **always** fails reading geometry objects - it's not that iWork's for some, but fails for others. Then has this ever worked at all ? It appears so. You say "it worked well until now".  So that implies something has changed: the processing changed. Or the data being processed changed.

Comment: You also say: "All SdoGeometry are ok and stored in mongoDb". How did that happen ? Using the same application ? Or through some other path. SDO_GEOMETRY is an object type that itself contains other object types and variable length arrays. Reading them is more convoluted than reading plain scalars, including strings. What is the `DbDataReader` class ? Is that provided by MongoDB ? Are you sure it does support the reading of Oracle object types ?

Comment: One possible way around is to convert the SDO_GEOMETRY types to a string or binary notation: OGC WKT, GeoJSON, GML or the binary WKB encoding. It all depends on what you do with this information once it is in MongoDB. Having it as a GeoJSON string is probably the most portable and easiest to process.

Comment: Yes it works well when MongoDb is empty. Always. Yes, SdoGeometry is converted to WKT after being read. But when the error occurs, it fails before being converted. I can do it also inside Oracle sql query (SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY) but it's not working on 4D geometries. That it's weird, SdoGeometry is ok only on the first run. Maybe the SdoGeometry class is unloaded from the assembly sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution !

By simply adding, in the first statement of my program, an Oracle (dummy) query making a select on a SdoGeometry type field of an arbitrarily chosen table.

I think this forces the SdoGeometry type to load.

So as I understand it the bug was happening while querying MongoDb data before loading Oracle SdoGeometry data, there was a problem loading in assembly (?).

Still, this solution works perfectly! Every time I try it works and as soon as I try to comment out the request forcing SdoGeometry to load, the error always occurs again. Additionally, the MongoDb data looks correct.

I don't understand everything in the details but it works !